# Algorithm to find when a polynomial with integer coefficients has a perfect square value

Tags: polynomials

Given a polynomial of the form $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integer coefficients, is there an efficient algorithm for finding integer values $x$ for which $f(x)$ is a perfect square? That is, for finding all integers $x$ where $f(x) = y^2$ for some integer $y$?

**EDITED TO ADD:** My apologies for not being clearer before. If it wasn't already obvious, what I'm wondering is whether there is an *efficient* algorithm, i.e., something better than just trying all possibilities.

For example, an algorithm that finds the smallest such $x > 0$ and which runs in constant time (or at least something better than $O(x)$) would qualify.

Comment: I think there should be an algorithm. I think there's always only finitely many $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a perfect square. For example, if $a = 1$, then for large $x$, $x^2 < f(x) < (x+1)^2$ and thus $f(x)$ is not a perfect square. Similarly, if $a=3$, then for large enough $x$, $(x+1)^2 < f(x) < (x+2)^2$. So I guess the algorithm could be, for given $a$, initially calculate how large "for large $x$" (this can be done), and then check values under that large $x$.

Comment: @mathworker21 For ***odd*** $a$, there is always an integer solution $x$. Kindly see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^2=x^2+ax+b$, $(2y)^2=4x^2+4ax+4b=(2x+a)^2+4b-a^2$, $4b-a^2=(2y)^2-(2x+a)^2$, so we want to express $4b-a^2$ as a difference of two squares.

Such expressions arise from, and only from, factorizations of $4b-a^2$ of the form $4b-a^2=mn$ with $m,n$ both even or both odd; we get
$$
4b-a^2=\left({m+n\over2}\right)^2-\left({m-n\over2}\right)^2
$$ and then $y=(m+n)/4$, $x=(m-n-2a)/4$.

So the algorithm is, compute $4b-a^2$; find all factorizations $4b-a^2=mn$ with $(m+n)/4$ and $(m-n-2a)/4$ both integers; that gives you all the values of $x$ and $y$ that work.

All of these computations take negligible time, except (for very large values of $a$ and/or $b$) the factorization of $4b-a^2$. That can't be helped; if you had a superfast way to find $x$ and $y$, you'd also have a superfast way of factoring large numbers.

Comment: Your last comment is intriguing. Given $$x^2+ax+b = y^2$$ for ***odd*** $a$, then there is a superfast way to find INTEGER $x,y$ namely, $$x = \frac{(a-r)^2-4b}{4r}$$ $$y = \frac{a^2-r^2-4b}{4r}$$ where we set $r=\pm1$, though I don't know if this also implies a superfast way to factor large numbers.

Comment: @Tito, chances are it leads to a trivial factorization like $1\times(4b-a^2)$.

Comment: I did the math this very minute. Alas it was the trivial factorization $1\times(4b-a^2)$. <Sigh.> At least, it is a superfast way to find $x,y$ for odd $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is:
$$ f(x) = x^2+ax+b $$
and you seek the form:
$$ y^2 = x^2+ax+b $$
for some integer $y$ to find $x$. We must solve for $x$ hence let us make the quadratic equation equal to zero:
$$ 0 = x^2+ax+b-y^2 $$
The solution to this equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) is:
$$ x_{1,2} = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4(b-y^2)}}{2}$$ 
For this to have a solution in the set of integer numbers the condition $ a^2-4(b-y^2) \geq 0 $ must be satisfied. As you are seeking for integer values of $x$ then you should only check whether the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integer in your algorithm for the given constants in the solution.

One more condition that you could test for integer solutions is whether $ -a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4(b-y^2)} $ is divisible by $2$. If it is then you have your integer solutions.

Here is a flowchart of the algorithm:
[image]

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes I am searching through all values of $y$. This is better in a way that you have to check if a number is divisible by $2$ in that is all. If you would search through all values of $x$ you would always get an integer answer for which you would have to check if it is a perfect square. It is obviously easier to check if a number is divisible by $2$ rather than if it is a square number.

Comment: @mathworker21 I wouldn't agree with you. When I am checking the divisibility by $2$ I am checking if the number is divisible by $2$ and not if it is an integer because $-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4(b-y^2}$ can be an integer but if it is not divisible by $2$ then it is not an integer solution for $x$.

Comment: The main advantage of my solution is that for knowing if there exists an answer you just have to check the divisibility by $2$ which is easier than checking if $ x^2+ax+b $ is a perfect square.

Comment: I am not trolling you. I check the divisibility by reading the remainder when dividing by 2. I am not wasting your time, you are wasting your own time. I don't understand why would you be so triggered. If you don't like my answer then don't bother with it.

Comment: We clearly aren't gonna come to an agreement so I will stop here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the equation,

$$x^2+ax+b =y^2$$

has infinitely many *rational* solutions given by,

$$x = \frac{(a-n)^2-4b}{4n}$$
$$y = \frac{a^2-n^2-4b}{4n}$$

for *any* rational $n$. But you want ***integer*** $(x,y)$. For **odd** a, then an obvious choice is $n = \pm 1$ and $(x,y)$ become integers.